# Find a better venue

Tags: grammaticality, present-tense

The context is that a researcher has found that the company is not very supportive for long-term research, and here's the advice of his friend to him:

> Two ways - either you convince the company to support long-term
>   research, which is more difficult, or you **find a better venue** for
>   conducting long-term research.

Is **find a better venue** grammatical? The meaning is to let him find a better company or research institute to pursue his goal.

Comment: Can you tell us something about why you're in doubt about whether "find a better venue" is grammatical?

Comment: @BenKovitz I am not a native speaker, just to make sure it conveys the right thing.

Comment: The short answer is "Yes, it's fine." To write a helpful longer answer, it helps to know more about why that phrase in particular seemed dubious to you—but I understand that often it's hard to put this sort of thing into words, especially regarding a non-native language.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's grammatical.

It might seem strange because one would not normally say "You find a better venue" as a complete sentence. To give advice, one would use the imperative mood and say "Find a better venue." Or to address the other person with "you", one would say "You, find a better venue" (with a comma, or a pause and a change of intonation in speech).

What's happening here is that the author is presenting two alternatives to be understood as mutually exclusive and jointly exhaustive; in other words, "these are your only two options." Other languages might use the subjunctive mood for the hypothetical possibilities, but in English, one way to do it is to use the simple present tense. The simple present in English seldom means "this is happening now," of course. Here's another very typical example:

> You really have two choices when it comes to dealing with an angry customer. **Either you attack the problem** head-on and attempt to fix it, or **you ignore it** and hope it goes away.
>
> <sup>Source: [*'C' If You Agree*](https://books.google.com/books?id=WTlRAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA54&dq=%22either%20you%22) by Lynn Blackwood.</sup>

The word "either" isn't necessary. This also indicates that you have exactly the two options indicated:

> **You make your present job better**, or **you find a better job**.

Introducing the alternatives with "Either you…" helps introduce the fact that you're talking about hypothetical possibilities for what "you" could do. As usual in English, where we use the same few grammatical constructs for a wide variety of meanings, we sometimes add redundant words, like "either", to help clarify. (Omitting "either" here is actually more emphatic.)

If you're wondering if there's a rule for this or if it's an isolated idiom, I think that as usual, English is borrowing a construct used in one context to help suggest a similar meaning in a different context. Rather than apply a rule, you just have to "get" the parallel with other uses of the construct. Here's another kind of sentence where the simple present is used "subjunctively":

> When the dog bites, when the bee stings,
>   When I'm feeling sad,
>   I simply **remember my favorite things**
>   And then I **don't feel so bad**.
>
> <sup>Source: Well-known lyrics to "[My Favorite Things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Favorite_Things_(song))", a [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33o32C0ogVM) from *The Sound of Music.*</sup>

As suggested by the "When…" clauses, which provide conditions, there is no assertion that "remembering my favorite things" is happening in the present. Using the simple present in this context indicates that "remember my favorite things" is hypothetical, describing a response to those conditions *whenever* they occur. Continuing the simple present after "And then…" indicates that "not feeling so bad" is the inevitable result. The simple present often frames timeless generalities; e.g. "Day inevitably **follows** night."

That's not exactly the same as the situation described in your friend's advice, which is a future response to the present situation—but it's close enough that it's natural in English to use the same grammatical construct for both. Notice the slight difference here:

> When the dog bites, etc., I **will** simply remember my favorite things.

The real lyrics from the song use the simple present tense to state the speaker's customary or characteristic response. The future tense expresses that the speaker *resolves* to respond that way in the future.

I suspect that the use of the simple present for hypothetical actions as well as the consequences that follow them in time is understood as extended use of the "historical present", but it's hard to prove this conclusively. The "historical present" is the use of the simple present tense to narrate past events or tell stories: "[John Wilkes Booth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wilkes_Booth) **walks** into Ford's Theater, and **then** he **hides** behind Lincoln's box. **When** the play **begins**, he **gets out** his gun…"